# Android Front camera size

Tags: android, camera

I work on a android app who takes pictures with front camera.
I use getSupportedPictureSizes() and the best size on my phone is 640x480.
If i set the picture size with an another it failed.
my phone is a samsung galaxy grand 2. Android(4.4.2)

Why when i take a selfie with the native app on my phone, the size of the pict is 720x1280 like the size of my screen or the size of the preview?

how did they do?

Comment: The native app can cheat, as it can use private APIs that are not available via the Android SDK to ordinary developers.